# Why do I not see the Tabular model designer window when creating new projects?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, tabular, ssas-tabular

Why can I not see this window when I create a new Tabular project?
Is it possible to get it?

[image: "Tabular model designer" dialog box]

Answer (score 1):

Because you previously selected the option "do not show this message again"

To make it appear again during a new project creation:

1. Open Visual Studio's "Options" dialog.
2. Type "Tabular" in the search box.
3. In the "New project settings" tab, check the option "Ask default project settings for each new project created".

[image]